# How to switch between two storyboards without interrupting animation?(swift 3)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, segue

I have two view controllers with rotating labels(animation)

how can I switch between view controllers without the animation to stop? or initializing again? so I guess both will run at the same time.

I tried segue push, unwind, pop but that just kills the animation.

Comment: Try subclassing segue. When u add segue to view controller just add that class to that segue, you ll surely get tutorials for this.

Comment: Your animation is a subview of some superview. Changing controllers changes the views, so you have to add your animation again to a new view. Maybe try put your animation to the UIWindow?

Comment: subclassing segue? do you mean a custom segue :)?

Comment: Did you look at UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioncoordinator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Using pageViewController will get the job done without doing any interruptions!

Thank you